# Althought my unittest fails in python, jenkins still builds successfully. Why isn't the build failing?

Tags: python, jenkins, python-unittest

Although my unittest fails in python, jenkins still builds successfully. Why isn't the build failing?

My unittest code is:

```
from main import IsOdd

import unittest
class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):

def testOne(self):
    self.failUnless(IsOdd(1))

def testTwo(self):
    self.failIf(IsOdd(2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

my console output is :

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: testTwo (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in testTwo
    self.failIf(IsOdd(3))
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Yet my jenkins build still builds successfully. What should I do?

Comment: How are the tests being run from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

There's not nearly enough info to answer this.  Ultimately, Jenkins is a simple tool- if the process it is running returns a 0, it shows the build as passing, and if it doesn't it shows it as failed.  If you're doing something like running a shell script to run your tests, you'll have to build in a check like

```
if line[-1].startswith("FAILED"):
    return 1
```

Tell us more about how your job is set up and how you expect it to recognize a failure and you could get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins interprets the exit codes of programs that it runs. Exit code `0` means everything is okay. So if your tests fail, your program should return a non-zero exit code, e.g., `1`, which it very likely doesn't.

To test that, run your tests manually on the command line and then enter execute

```sh
user@localhost$ $?
```

to display the last command's exit code.